# Javascript variable in same django template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

In my django app there is a javascript modal which retrieves all the available images from backend.(I send a django variable in the template and display all the images on modal)

In the app I have Gridster widgets which already have some images on them which are put up via JSON

On each button there is a `+` button which opens the modal and user can add images on the widget from which the `+` button is clicked

**Current State**

The modal which opens when I click `+` button currently has all the images.Since there are images present on the widgets I dont want those images to appear in the modal.

**Desired Output**

I want the modal to update in realtime.Of all the available images modal should only show the images which are not present on the widget.

**What I have done so far**

The images on widget have their  names in a `textarea` on widget.As soon as I delete an image the name of that image gets deleted from `textarea`.

In js I extract the content of that `textarea` and delete it from the django variable which is sent from template(it has names of all the images in it)

So the resulting variable `filteredBrands` is the one that has the names of images that are not present on the particular widget.

I am not getting how I can pass this variable in the loops which is currently getting all the images so that only those images will be rendered which are not on a particular widget.

JS function which generates the `filteredBrands` variable

```
 var parentLI;
    var selectedImageSRC = "";
    var imageNameValue;
    var brandsFromBackend;

    $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
        parentLI = $(this).closest('li');                         //Getting the widget in which on which the + button is pressed   
        imageNameValue = parentLI.children('.imagenames').val();   //Getting list existing of images which are there on widget from the textarea
        brandsFromBackend = document.getElementById("myVar").value;  //Getting the django template variable having all the images
        brandsFromBackend = brandsFromBackend.replace(/'/g, '"');    
        brandsFromBackend = JSON.parse(brandsFromBackend);    //Converting django variable to JS array
        console.log(brandsFromBackend);
        ////Convert brands on widget to filteredBrands 
        imageNameValueArray = imageNameValue.split(',')       //Converting the textarea(existing images list) content to list           
       console.log(imageNameValueArray);

         //Loop that removes the images which are present on widgets from the array having all the images(django variable JS array)
         var filteredBrands = brandsFromBackend; 
        console.log(filteredBrands);

        for(var j = 0; j < imageNameValueArray.length; j++) {

                for (var i=filteredBrands.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (filteredBrands[i] === imageNameValueArray[j]) {
                        filteredBrands.splice(i, 1);
                        // break;       //<-- Uncomment  if only the first term has to be removed
                    }
                }
        }


        console.log("filteredBrands");
        console.log(filteredBrands);

        brandsFiltered = JSON.stringify(filteredBrands);
        console.log(brandsFiltered);            //Final list of filtered images which are to be shown in the modal. I want to pass this variable to

        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    });
```

Loop which generates images for modal

```
  {% for file in brands %}  
        {% load static %}
            <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl" src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/brands/{{file}}" alt=""></div>
        {% endfor %}
```

`brands` is the variable which I send from views.py(It has all the images in it.Here I want `filteredBrands`(having only those images which are not on widget and generated in JS in the same template)

HTML by which I get brands

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="variable" value="{{ brands }}">
```

To get the idea of entire thing please go over this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3k8sz2mg/).It is not exactly reflecting my app(since I have django) but I hope it will help in getting idea of other things atleast.

**Update 1**

Please someone help me with this because I am not even sure if this is doable/correct way for it.I am completely clueless about this